# Search complexity of Dictionary<TKey,TValue> vs List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I've been doing some reading on the generic Dictionary class and the general advice is to use Dictionary if you need really fast access to an item matching a specific key. This is because a dictionary is using a type-safe Hashtable under the hood. When accessing items the search complexity is O(1) in dictionaries whereas in a List we would need to loop through EVERY SINGLE item until we find a match making the complexity O(n).

I wrote a little console app to see just how significant the difference between the two would be. The app stores 10 million items in each collection and attempts to access the second last item. The time difference between the List and Dictionary<TKey,TValue> is only one second, making the dictionary a winner but only just.

Question - can you provide an example(verbal is fine) where using a Dictionary vs a List would  yield significant performance improvements?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var iterations = 10000000;//10 million

        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        var value1 = GetSecondLastFromDictionary(iterations);
        sw.Stop();
        var t1 = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
        sw.Restart();

        var value2 = GetSecondLastFromList(iterations);

        sw.Stop();
        var t2 = sw.Elapsed.ToString(); 

        Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary - {t1}\nList - {t2}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string GetSecondLastFromList(int iterations)
    {
        var collection = new List<Test>();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            collection.Add(new Test { Key = i, Value = $"#{i}" });
        return collection.Where(e => e.Key == iterations - 1).First().Value;
    }

    private static string GetSecondLastFromDictionary(int iterations)
    {
        var collection = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            collection.Add(i, $"#{i}");
        return collection[iterations - 1];
    }
}
class Test
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the question ? You already answer it. What other explanation do you need ?

Comment: I feel like this isn't a fair test. You already know the mathematical advantages of a Dictionary and a List. Actual performance will vary based on hardware and many many other factors.

Comment: You're including the time taken to *populate* the collection with the time to fetch the item from it. I'd expect the population part to take *far* longer than the access, for both collection types. That's also not the normal use case for collections - normally a collection it populated once (and maybe modified later, of course) but then accessed multiple times. I'd also strongly advise the use of BenchmarkDotNet to avoid many of the common issues of benchmarking.

Comment: So to answer your question: "can you provide an example(verbal is fine) where using a Dictionary vs a List would yield significant performance improvements?" - in the far more normal case, where you're populating the collection once, but accessing it thousands or millions of times.

Comment: @JonSkeet Insert is O(1) on the List, so when only inserting, it is better than the dictionary. (Unless permanent reallocation is necessary, but this can be avoided by already creating the list with the correct initial size)

Comment: @PMF: Inserting into a dictionary is O(1) as well - the complexity doesn't actually tell you which is faster. (I'd normally expect inserting into a list to be faster, but that doesn't follow from "Insert is O(1) on the List".

Comment: @JonSkeet I think we're talking about the same thing here. While _in theory_ inserting into a dictionary is O(1), any practical implementation of a dictionary will be O(log(n)) or something along that.

Comment: @PMF: I'm not at all convinced it will be. I'd expect it to take longer to insert into a dictionary simply because it needs to compute the hash value of the key... but I'd still expect it to be O(1) unless internal reorganisation is required. But all of that is irrelevant, really - the bigger point is that when trying to demonstrate the benefits of dictionaries over lists for lookup speed, you should be measuring *the lookup speed*. Populating a huge collection and then only finding a single element in it simply isn't a representative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own example is fine to show where using a Dictionary yields significant performance improvements.  The problem is you're not looking at the right thing.  Your code spends a lot of time creating the dictionary or list and then does just one access of it.  You need to separate out the collection creation and time multiple accesses of the item.

The code below does this.  I get multiple accesses of the dictionary take 0.001s, whereas of the list the same number of accesses takes 2 minutes 32 seconds.  Assuming I've done that right I think it shows dictionaries are faster for access.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var iterations = 100000;

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var dict = CreateDict(iterations);
        var list = CreateList(iterations);
        sw.Start();
        GetSecondLastFromDictionary(iterations, dict);
        sw.Stop();
        var t1 = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
        sw.Restart();
        GetSecondLastFromList(iterations, list);
        sw.Stop();
        var t2 = sw.Elapsed.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary - {t1}\nList - {t2}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, string> CreateDict(int iterations)
    {
        var collection = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            collection.Add(i, $"#{i}");
        return collection;
    }

    private static List<Test> CreateList(int iterations)
    {
        var collection = new List<Test>();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            collection.Add(new Test { Key = i, Value = $"#{i}" });
        return collection;
    }

    private static void GetSecondLastFromList(int iterations, List<Test> collection)
    {
        string test;
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            test = collection.Where(e => e.Key == iterations - 1).First().Value;
    }

    private static void GetSecondLastFromDictionary(int iterations, Dictionary<int, string> collection)
    {
        string test;
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            test = collection[iterations - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: When accessing the second-last element of the list, it doesn't make much difference, but `collection.Where(e => e.Key == iterations - 1).First()` is poor. Use `collection.First(e => e.Key == iterations - 1)` instead. Your code would _always_ iterate over the whole list, even if the first element was searched.

Comment: Note also that this is the worst-case time for the list, but not necessarily for the dictionary.

Comment: @PMF: While I would generally prefer to use `.First(condition)` as well, your claim that "Your code would always iterate over the whole list" is incorrect. `Where` is lazy, and `First` will stop after the first element.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, thanks for clarifying, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Why are you looping through the dictionary in GetSecondLastFromDictionary instead of just accessing it by key?

Comment: Denys Wessels, I'm not.  I'm accessing the same value by the same key 100,000 times and discarding the results.  Which looks dumb, but we're trying to see how fast accessing the value is.  Doing it once doesn't really show us that very accurately because it's so fast.  I do the same thing with the list, time both, and then we can compare.  To be clear, in the code above iterations=100,000, so the line `test = collection[iterations - 1]` accesses collection[99999], which is '#99999', on every iteration of the loop.  You can see this if you put in a breakpoint.